# Localized String compare

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

I am using a `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to get the array of local `sectionIndexTitles`.
Now I want to check a string if it starts with some element from these sectionIndexTitles.

Assuming my language is Korean, `sectionIndexTitles` are this:

```
"ㄱ,ㄴ,ㄷ,ㄹ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅅ,ㅇ,ㅈ,ㅊ,ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅎ,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,#"
```

### Question

**How do I check if the String "나비" starts with "ㄴ"?**

The problem is that the first "character" is "나" and "ㄴ" never stands by itself in a character. So it seems like the `sectionIndexTitles` should actually contain first character-combinations as e.g. `나`.

```
"ㄴ".characters.first // "ㄴ"
"나비".characters.first // "나"
"나비".hasPrefix("ㄴ") // false
"나비".localizedStandardRange(of: "ㄴ") // nil
```

#### Update, following up on your comment:

```
"나비".range(of: "ㄴ") // nil
```

#### Update 2: Question

**How can I create alphabetic section headers like "A", "B", "C", ... and put in localized string elements like "나비"?**

In e.g. Korean there are various combinations for the first "character", so the 
`sectionIndexTitles` from `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` (e.g. "ㄴ") can't be used to sort elements into the right section

Comment: sorry but `"나비".range(of: "ㄴ")` what does it return? (just asking. I never had this kind of problems, but your question is really interesting! it's not quite common..)

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29224218/3178454) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33418270/3178454) may help

Comment: @ddb thanks, I updated my question after I tried out `range`

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I am using the sectionIndexTitles for scrolling to an element in a collectionView -> I don't have any more information than "ㄴ" and it's impossible to compare with all combinations that start with "ㄴ"

Answer (score 1):

*Zooming* on characters, I see that `"나"` and `"ㄴ"` *start* with two different visual elements.

The "L" visual element in the first case has a *curved horizontal part*

[image]

while in the second (the letter you're trying to match) doesn't.

[image]

So I think that, if you want to hierarchically organize data, strings that starts with `"나"` should be simply included in the `"#"` section (as far as I understand studying `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` at [this tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/)).

Basically if `"나비".hasPrefix("ㄴ")` is `false`, then it is `false`... and so it should be handled.

Comment: These are 2 fundamentally different strings: `\u{b098}\u{be44}` vs. `\u{3134}`. The fact that they both start as an L-like shape is irrelevant. It's like I (uppercase i) and l (lowercase ell) look the same in Arial doesn't mean that they are equal

Comment: That means that the `sectionIndexTitles` don't actually return valid first characters and is therefore not useful for e.g section headers.

Comment: @MarkHim, I think yes